# mutation observer of iframe is removed when click a href of iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After attach a mutation observer inside the iframe, does pressing the `<a href=''>` button inside the iframe remove the mutation observer?

I wrote the code to allow the mutation observer to detect changes of the body element, but it doesn't detect. I wonder if I wrote the wrong code or if what I thought above is correct.

If the mutation observer is deleted, should I register the mutation observer with the parent frame to which the iframe belongs?

```
let config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: false };
let htmlBody = document.querySelector('body');

let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
         console.log("Mutation calling");
    });
});

observer.observe(htmlBody, config);
```

Comment: I inject this code through `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to iframe document(child document of main)

Comment: Do you re-inject the code to a new page the link opens?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same as any other navigation: Javascript is terminated in preparation for the new page. That it's in an iframe or that it was injected doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ouroborus Is clicking '<a href>' erasing iframe node and creating a new iframe node? I thought until now the existing iframe node would stay the same, and just the internal head, body, and properties would change .

Comment: @Teemu I didn't re-inject because I thought the mutation observer would stay the same.

Comment: Why .. how would that stay the same, the old page is gone, and a new page is loaded ..?

Comment: @4rigener No, the iframe is the same iframe. However, the document the iframe contains is a new document. The injected javascript is tied to the document, not the iframe (same as how, in a regular page, javascript is tied to the page, not the browser window).

Comment: @Teemu If  click the button on the main, it will switch to a new page, but I thought iframe is different. If frame is also a transition to a new page, is existing iframe node removed and the iframe node of the new page is created? That means an iframe node with a new memory address value will be created?

Comment: @Ouroborus Aha, I see. So the iframe node has the same memory address value, but the existing javascript (including the mutation observer) belonging to  the document is cleared?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @Ouroborus Could you write down what you said as an answer? I'd like to adopt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Yes, the injected javascript is lost when navigation occurs.

Javascript is generally tied to the document, not the container (i.e: the browser, the iframe, etc.). Normally, when navigation occurs, any javascript running in that context is unloaded in order to prepare for the new document and its new javascript.

This doesn't change in the case of an iframe. The iframe is the viewing context and the iframe's document is still a document and still has the same semantics as it would had it been loaded normally. Being able to inject code into that document doesn't change things.

Comment: I get the answer that injected code is not lost when navigation occurs and code really do that. See [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68888784/how-to-prevent-hide-and-show-flickering-of-mutationobserver-for-iframe) I understand that your answer is assuming that iframe move to other domain. And upper answer's code is not lost because iframe is not moved to other domain. Is this right? I want to understand this concept accurately.

Comment: @4rigener That question's answer works by detecting when the iframe's inner context is switching  from one page to another and then re-injects the mutation observer code into that new page. The hosting page (the page containing the `<iframe>` element) does the injection and monitors the iframe. Since the hosting page itself does not unload, its scripting context remains active.

Comment: Then difference between mutation observer at other question and mutation observer at other question's answer is when is mutation observer is inserted? And what caused difference is `unload` at `fw.addEventListener('unload', checkFrameReady);`. Did I get it right?

Comment: The main difference between the implementation in that question and its answer is the context in which the mutation observer is running. In the question, it's running in the host page. In the answer, it's running in the iframe's page. The `unload` handler is just there to re-inject and re-start the code related to the mutation observer when the iframe navigates to a different page.